# Test Fails Only in IntelliJ, but Works with Maven Command Line

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Ultimate Edition)

I have a test that runs fine from the command line when using mvn, but when I run the test from IntelliJ I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue, offset=6

Under "Structure for New Projects", I have "Project SDK" set to the same JDK as what I have in the command line. I have already tried deleting the .idea directory and *.iml files, then reloading the project. I have also tried invalidating caches and restarting.

When I delegate the IntelliJ runner to Maven, the test works the same as the command line, but this is not ideal as you don't get the selectable tree of failed tests.

Comment: Check which java jdk version is used by intellij https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under?page=3

Comment: @Lia I set it up to use JDK 8 with Choose Runtime, but IntelliJ won't start with that version. I had to manually delete the `idea.jdk` file to be able to start IntelliJ again.

Comment: Make sure the [project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html#project-sdk) and [modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html#change-module-sdk) JDK is set to the correct JDK version. And that the Java target level is also correctly set in [Java Compiler Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html) - see **Per-module bytecode version** description here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html#compiler

Comment: @Andrey Project SDK: 1.8, Project language level: 8, Module SDK: 1.8

Comment: Can you provide a sample project?